# Rails and haml, how to add id and class selectors to link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I've been looking around how to add an `id` selector to a `link_to` helper using `haml`, is that possible?

```
  a .haml - %a#booked{:href => "index.haml"} Link 1    

  b .html.erb - booking.html.erb - <%= link_to "Link 1", booking_path, :id => "booked" %>

  c .haml.erb - booking.haml.erb - ...??
```

Which would be the equivalent of b in haml?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`link_to` works exactly the same way in haml as it does in erb. So this will do what you want:

```
= link_to "Link 1", booking_path, :id => "booked"
#=> <a id="booked" href="/bookings">Link 1</a>
```

You can also assign a class attribute in this way:

```
= link_to "Link 1", booking_path, :id => "booked", :class => "some_class"
#=> <a id="booked" class="some_class" href="/bookings">Link 1</a>
```

More on how to insert ruby code in haml: [Inserting ruby](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_)

And, just so there are no doubts about passing ids and classes to `link_to`, here is an example [from the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
link_to "Articles", articles_path, :id => "news", :class => "article"
#=> <a href="/articles" class="article" id="news">Articles</a>
```

Comment: Hi @shioyama, that approach will add an id the url. and what I'm looking for is add a id selector like <a id="style" href="#">link 1 </a>.

Comment: That's exactly what it will do: `<a id="booked" href="...">Link 1</a>`. It will not add it to the url.

Comment: I've added an example from the docs on `link_to`, as you can see the `id` will get correctly assigned to the `a` tag, not appended to the URL.

Comment: @shioyama Is there a way to use the more modern ruby notation where it's like: `{class:'article'}` ?

Comment: Sure, why not? `link_to "Articles", articles_path, id: "news", class: "article"`

Comment: same with me , that added to url , i didn't provide "articles_path"

Answer (score 4):

To add an id selector in haml using link_to you have to specify two hashes.

```
e.g = link_to "Link 1", {booking_path, extra arg...}, {:id => 'booked'}
```

An important Ruby idiom is **poetry mode**: the ability to omit parentheses and curly braces when the parsing is unambiguous. Most commonly, Ruby programmers may omit parentheses around arguments to a method call, and omit curly braces when the last argument to a method call is a hash. Hence the following two method calls are equivalent, given a method **link_to** that takes one string argument and one hash argument:

Without curly braces, there’s no way to tell whether this call is trying to pass a hash with two keys or two hashes of one key each. Therefore poetry mode can only be used when there’s a single hash argument and it’s the last argument.

Patterson, David; Fox, Armando (2012-08-24). Engineering Long-Lasting Software: An Agile Approach Using SaaS and Cloud Computing, Beta Edition (Kindle Locations 1973-1975). Strawberry Canyon LLC. Kindle Edition.

Comment: You don't *need* to pass two hashes for this case, `link_to "Link 1", booking_path, :id => "booked"` will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for using the curly brackets, not using them is why this wasn't working for me. `<%= link_to 'Video Index', controller: 'videos', :id => 'index' %>` output `<a href="/videos?id=index">Video Index</a>` but changing it to this `{controller: 'videos'}` makes it properly output `<a id="index" href="/videos">Video Index</a>`